# reading Array randomly

Tags: java

I've a program & I wont to read ARRAY randomly I don't have error with program
 but during output I have null value can you give me the solution ...

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ReadDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties prob = new Properties();
        String word [] = new String [20] ;
        try{
            prob.load( new FileInputStream("words.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        for(int i=1; i<6; i++){         
            String temp = prob.getProperty(""+i);
            word[i] = temp;
            Random ran = new Random ();

            String Val = word[ran.nextInt(word.length)];

            System.out.println(Val);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your array has a length of 20 and you are filling only 5 values: `for(int i=1; i<6; i++){`. That explains null values.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your array has size 20 but your loop has only 5 iterations.
2. Your loop starts at the wrong index (partially related)
3. You are doing the random polling of the `word` array before it's actually finished being populated with data:

Change it from:

```
for(int i=1; i<6; i++){         
    String temp = prob.getProperty(""+i);
    word[i] = temp;
    Random ran = new Random ();
    String Val = word[ran.nextInt(word.length)];
    System.out.println(Val);
}
```

To:

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++){         
    String temp = prob.getProperty(""+i);
    word[i] = temp;
}

for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
    Random ran = new Random ();
    String Val = word[ran.nextInt(word.length)];
    System.out.println(Val);
}
```

Comment: i changed now but a some time i have null but less than before can i use while before second for loop

Comment: @rawaztariq you can try, but as others have pointed out, the bigger issue is how you are actually getting the string for `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

Your output could null because `prob.getProperty` is returning null for the key of the randomly selected index, but more likely the issue is that the randomly generated index is outside the range of 5 values being filled.

Two recommendations:

1. Never ignore exceptions. Most likely, `prob` is failing to be loaded due to an exception.  Instead, print the exception: `e.printStackTrace()`.
2. Ensure that your expected properties being loaded actually have the keys 1-5 that you assume exist in filling your `words` array.